# adding and deleting value blocks in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would have a question regarding VisualBasics for Application (VBA) in Excel.

I need to include two buttons on my worksheet(add and delete).

[image]

When pressing the add button a new block of values should be added below one existing block, separated by a blank row.

[image]

When pressing the delete button the a block should become deleted.

[image]

-> see pictures

My current state is the following one.

Copy and paste works, but only for one single line not for multiple lines

```
Sub AddLibs()
Dim r As ListObject
Dim c As Integer
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "test"
   
    
   
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("data").ListRows(ActiveCell.Row).Range.Select
    Set r = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("data")
    c = r.Range.Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("data").Resize Range("A1:B" & c)
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightorAbove
        
    
   
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
ActiveSheet.Protect "test", True, True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint!
I forgot my current state. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you copy-pasting?

I have just put three values in A1, A2 and A3, and I have run this piece of code:

```
Range("B1:B3").Value = Range("A1:A3").Value
```

The values from A1:A3 have been copied to B1:B3. As you see, there's a very easy way to copy ranges without using the clipboard (`.Copy`, `.Paste`).

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking in a too complex way.  Your answer helped me to find a much easier, working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found an appropriate solution.
Implementation looks like this

Adding a block

```
Sub AddLibs()
    If Cells(Selection.Row, 1).Value = "name" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "test"
        For counter = 0 To 3
            ActiveCell.Offset(counter + 4, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            ActiveCell.Offset(counter + 4, -1).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(counter, -1)
        Next counter
        ActiveSheet.Protect "test", True, True
    Else
        MsgBox "Please klick into a library Cell to add a new one!", , "Not possible action"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

deleting a block

```
Sub DeleteLibs()
    If Cells(Selection.Row, 1).Value = "name" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "test"
        For counter = 3 To 0 Step -1
            ActiveCell.Offset(counter, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        Next counter
        ActiveSheet.Protect "test", True, True
    Else
        MsgBox "Please klick into the library Cell and push button again to delete!", , "Not possible action"
    End If
End Sub
```